# Inserting images into slides from a URL in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am setting up a deck to automatically create a new slide with each row in a spreadsheet.

Each row has a different picture attached to it, which has the URL in a column on the source spreadsheet, and I would like this image to be inserted into the slide, alongside some text.

The code I am using to populate the text fields is below - this works fine:

```
// Insert a new slide by duplicating the master slide.
let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();

// Populate data in the slide that was created
slide.replaceAllText("{{ItemName}}", column[0]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{SKU}}", column[1]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{Price}}", column[2]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{Count}}", column[3]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{Composition}}", column[4]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{Analytics}}", column[5]);
slide.replaceAllText("{{Description}}", column[6]);
**slide.insertImage(???);**
```

I would like to be able to add the image URL as a new column to the sheet and have the script pull this in and convert it into an image on the slide

Comment: I think that if your image URL is the direct public link of the image, your script works. So, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. So, in order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue?

Comment: It works - but it inserts the same image into every slide. I want it to read the unique URL from each row in the spreadsheet and put that image into that slide.

The flow is:
Use 2nd slide as a template
For each row create a new slide by duplicating the master slide and replacing the template variables (that is the code above)

On the template slide, I have an image placeholder and each slide will have a different image, the URL's for which are in column 8. I can insert a single URL into the code, but can't get it to pull the unique one from each row

Comment: I am new to this - so not sure what is the most helpful detailed flow sorry!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current Spreadsheet from your question, your showing script and reply. So I cannot think of your current issue. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.